# Install a plugin to Liferay's editor

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp

I have a Liferay DXP installation and I would like to install a plugin to the editor. The plugin is [base64image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/base64image).

I was following [this official guide](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-new-behavior-to-an-editor) so I created a class generally like this:

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = DynamicInclude.class)
public class CKEditorBase64ImageDynamicInclude implements DynamicInclude {

        private BundleContext bundleContext;


        @Override
        public void include(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String key) throws IOException {
                Bundle bundle = bundleContext.getBundle();
                URL entryURL = bundle.getEntry("/META-INF/resources/html/editors/ckeditor/extension/base64_images.js");
                StreamUtil.transfer(entryURL.openStream(), response.getOutputStream());
        }

        @Override
        public void register(DynamicIncludeRegistry dynamicIncludeRegistry) {
                dynamicIncludeRegistry.register("com.liferay.frontend.editors.web#ckeditor#onEditorCreate");

        }

        @Activate
        protected void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) {
                this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
        }

}
```

It should include the `base64_images.js` file where it initializes the editor. But it never works, regardless what the content of the file is. What is wrong with that?

I would like to add that the plugin files (JavaScript code) are part of my Liferay theme. I wanted `base64_images.js` to call its API but it also might not be the correct way how to do it.

Comment: You should add information on what errors you are receiving.

Comment: There are none. There is just no impact on the portal.

Comment: is your bundle started ?